# Method App\Http\Controllers\todocontroller::validate does not exist error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7 and while validating my form fields I am getting this error:

"Method App\Http\Controllers\todocontroller::validate does not exist error."

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\todo;

class todocontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $todos= todo::all();
        return view('todo.home',compact('todos'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('todo.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $todo = new todo;
        $this->validate($request,[
            'body'=>'required',
            'title'=>'required|unique:todos',
        ]);
        $todo->body = $request->body;
        $todo->title = $request->title;
        $todo->save();
        return redirect('/todo');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $todo=todo::find($id);
        return view('todo.show',compact('todo'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $todo=todo::find($id);
        return view('todo.edit',compact('todo'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $todo = todo::find($id);
        $this->validate($request,[
            'body'=>'required',
            'title'=>'required',
        ]);
        $todo->body = $request->body;
        $todo->title = $request->title;
        $todo->updated_at = now();
        $todo->save();
        session()->flash('message','Updated Successfully!');
        return redirect('/todo');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $todo = todo::find($id);
        $todo -> delete();
        session()->flash('message','Deleted Successfully!');
        return redirect('/todo');
    }
}
```

error is in this code

```
$this->validate($request,[
                'body'=>'required',
                'title'=>'required|unique:todos',
            ]);
```

but as per laravel documentation my validate method is right.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong in my controller.
I have also googled for this error but no success.

I have also tried using these lines :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Validator;
```

But no success. Please help me since i am getting this error for last 10 days. I don't understand what to do now. Your help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use $pure = $request->validate([ 'body' =>  'required']);,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'body'=>'required',
    'title'=>'required|unique:todos',
]);

$todo = new todo;
$todo->body = $request->body;
$todo->title = $request->title;
$todo->save();

return redirect('/todo');
```

> If the validation fails, the proper response will automatically be generated. If the validation passes, our controller will continue executing normally.

Check [Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) in docs again.

Comment: @livianshrawnia Nice. Don't hesitate to vote up and/or accept answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

Although other answers might contain valid alternative way, `$this->validate(...)` should work without any problem in your controller. But you should make sure you haven't changed anything from standard Laravel base controller.

Default controller located [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php) looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

As you see it contains `ValidatesRequests` trait and this trait provides `validate` method. So take a look at your `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` file and make sure it looks like this above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
use Validator;
....
....

Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
])->validate();
```

link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#automatic-redirection

Comment: use Validator; @livianshrawnia

Comment: i already used that Dhruv Raval but no success. by the way thanks for your help. i got the solution by Tpojka's code. i was using 5.4 validate method

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an issue as I was trying to use it like this

```
$this->validate(request(), [
        "title" => "required",
     
    ]);
```

Made a silly mistake there.

make sure you use your controller from right place.
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;